# Accessing child node properties in Firebase RTD

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have .js file where I loop through Firebase real time database to find email and password of registered users which is stored under /users tree in database where each child is randomly generated unique id which has user information. I am getting email and password information from form element. Problem is the alert messages in checkMessage are not executed when email and password do not equal same. Alert message should be displayed but only page refreshes.

```
Database:
----/Users
--------/XJIGFDMDKGD
-------------email: "a@b.com"
-------------password: "12345"
--------/XJFGNRIENGJ
-------------email: "c@d.com"
-------------password: "67890"
```

My code:

```
document
  .getElementById('loginForm')
  .addEventListener('submit', formSubmit);

function formSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'block';

  // Get Values from the DOM
  let email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
  let password = document.querySelector('#password').value;

  //check message values
  checkMessage(email, password);


  //Form Reset After Submission
  //document.getElementById('loginForm').reset();

}
```

checkMessage function:

```
function checkMessage(email, password) {

  var usrs = firebase.database().ref('users');

  usrs.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    var user = snapshot.val();

    if (user.email == email) {
      if (user.password == password) {

      } else {
      }
    } else {
      document.querySelector('.alert2').style.display = 'block';
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector('.alert2').style.display = 'none';
      }, 7000);
      document.getElementById('loginForm').reset();
    }
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by syntax problem, an extra brace at the end of the following section of code, as well as a misplaced parentheses. Fixed solution:

```
  var users = firebase.database().ref('users');
  users.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    var user = snapshot.val();

    if (email == user.email) {
      if (password == user.password) {

      }
    } else {
      };
  });
```